# JAVA Maven false displaying of resources text files (like stressed letters) while execution without eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, utf-8, resources

The OS, I am working on, is Windows 8.

I am working on a Maven project using JAVA.

The final program is usable by French speaking people and English speaking people.

I am looking for a solution in order to display a little text encoded in UTF-8 written in a resource file when I launch my program without Eclipse.

- With Eclipse, when I run the main class as a java application without making an executable jar file, the stressed letters (like é,è) of the text loaded from a resource file are correctly displayed.
- When I launch my program, which is an executable jar file and is made by maven, without Eclipse, the stressed letters (like é,è) of the text loaded from a resource file are not correctly displayed.

Is it because, by default on Windows, the text files are saved by being encoded in ANSI (while using notepad++)?

Here is some lines of one of my pom files:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <!-- remaining code for maven-resources-plugin -->
         </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```

As I am a French developer, I am not sure I write correctly.
But I try to write the best as possible in order to improve my English writing.

For getting more details, do not hesitate to leave me a message.

I thank everybody by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did my project entirely in UTF-8; also for .java.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This looks very much like your setup. Notepad++ will show the encoding, which probably by default is Windows-1252 in your case. You can change the encoding both in eclipse and Notepad++.

[image: Notepad++ - Here in the lower menu one may convert to UTF-8]

Probably convert without BOM, as that character at file start is only for old Notepad.

Last point. Do not use FileReader/FileWriter as they use the default encoding. You probably use `getResource` anyway.

```
new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/..."),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
The argument StandardCharsets.UTF_8 was missing.
I have corrected my mistake by calling the adequate constructor InputStreamReader and appending the argument StandardCharsets.UTF_8 to the call of this constructor:
I hope I will have helped other developers.

Comment: @cardman So your question was incomplete: It was missing the key aspect to reproduce your problem. Please edit your question and add how you originally tried to load the resource.

Comment: @oberlis Is my question more precise?

Answer (score 0):

The encoding can be defined by using the following property:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

But if you have defined the above property than the encoding definition in the plugins is superfluous which means your plugin section can look like that:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </plugin>
```

All plugins having a default value for the [encoding](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding).

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

I have also used the variable "project.build.sourceEncoding" instead of the hard coded string "UTF-8" in order to use a generic code for my pom files.

I hope I will have helped other developers.